# Zend Framework 2 autoloading hybridauth Library

Tags: zend-framework2, autoload, hybridauth, zend-autoloader

I want to `autoload` **Hybridauth** external library in my `module` name "Account", I have included all libraries in the location

```
/var/www/ZendSkeletonApplication/module/Account/lib/hybridauth/Hybrid
```

Also in my `module.php` , I have the following namespaces

```
'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
             'namespaces' => array(
                 __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__.'/src/'.__NAMESPACE__,
                  'hybridauth' => __DIR__.'/lib/hybridauth/Hybrid',
             ),
         ),
```

And in `/var/www/ZendSkeletonApplication/module/Account/lib/hybridauth/Hybrid Auth.php` file I have put the namespace.

```
namespace hybridauth;
class Hybrid_Auth {
......
```

In my controller I have declared the namespace as

```
use hybridauth\Hybrid_Auth;
```

But now whenever I make a call to  `new Hybrid_Auth( $config );`, it shows error unable to load class.

I don't know what I am doing wrong here or weather I am following the correct way to autoload external libs in `ZF2`.

Any suggestion or Help !

Comment: Try this: 'hybridauth' => __DIR__.'/lib/hybridauth'

Comment: Is this your "hybridauth"? https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth If not, can you give me a link to the library?

Comment: @Pradeep no luck dude !

Comment: @RudolphGottesheim yep that is only

Comment: Then why don't you load it via Composer?

Comment: @RudolphGottesheim i didnt get any composer for hybrid ..

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean by that? [It's on Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/hybridauth/hybridauth)...

Comment: I meant hybrid composer installer for Zend, right now I made it work via autoload_class.php mapping but Still namespaces thing not working

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really don't get it. Have you tried installing it via Composer? Then you shouldn't have any autoloading issues.

Comment: @RudolphGottesheim yep I did that too , tried all possible permutation & combinations

Comment: @RudolphGottesheim done via composer , i needed to add an slash before class name :) Thanks mate for your help